# How to find the max of 3 indexes in a list?

Tags: python

Short and simple, let's say I have this list:

```
a = [["Bob","5","10","7","4.5","6.3","6.4"],["Charles","3","4","5","5.2","8.34","356.444"]]
```

I want to find to find the highest value of index 1,2 and 3 only (so the highest value out of 5,10 and 7 and then the highest out of 3, 4 and 5.

I'm not familiar with `max()`, however I have tried

```
for b in a:
   c = max(b[1],b[2],b[3])
   print(c)
```

And to no surprise it does not work.

How would I do this in the simplest way? I'm sure there is probably an easy method, if what I have said makes sense.

Comment: Do you want the highest value *per entry* or for all entries?

Comment: _"And to no surprise it does not work"_ It's surprising to me, actually. I ran the code and it executes successfully with no errors.

Comment: @Kevin His problem is that it was using the ordinal string values for comparison. He needed to cast his strings to integers. Of course he didn't specify that in the question, but it's a safe bet he doesn't want to compare the ordinal values.

Comment: In the example above, can you, please, post what you would expect the answer to be?  It's not clear to me from the question.  That is, the program is not printing what you'd want it to print.  Given the data that you use in your example, what do you want to see printed?

Comment: Well Id expect it to print 10, and then 5.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
>>> [max(map(float, el[1:4])) for el in a]
[10.0, 5.0]
```

This returns a list with the max of the 3 indexes (1,2,3) for each entry in the list.

Your original code was not working because you were calling `max()` on the numbers (as strings) before converting them. Therefore, changing

```
c = max(b[1],b[2],b[3])
```

to

```
c = max(int(b[1]),int(b[2]),int(b[3]))
```

would also give you the result you expected.

Comment: It's cleaner without the lambda function. `[max(map(float, el[1:4])) for el in a]`

Comment: @Alex I never knew I could do that, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @OP  If the indexes are always integers `int` can replace `float`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yeah, I just noticed he had some floating point numbers at the end, so I thought that it would be best to be more "generic".

Comment: I upvoted already, but your answer can be improved if you explain *why* his original code failed (comparing as strings and not numbers).

Comment: Ok that seems to work, how would I go about then sorting list a so that it would actually output the highest value first?

Comment: @Alex:  `sorted(result, reverse=True)` or `reversed(sorted(result))` or `result.sort(reverse=True)`.

Comment: If I make A this: [['Bob', '5', '10', '7', '4.5', '6.3', '6.4'], ['Charles', '3', '31', '5', '5.2', '8.34', '356.444'], ['Dan', '5', '15', '5', '5.2', '8.34', '356.444']] and then try to sort it, when I print a, it has not changed when it should output a[1] then a[2] then a[0]? Im probably really confusing everyone

Comment: As in I want it to sort the list in a based on the highest value from each list from highest to lowest

Comment: I could probably make it easier to undertstand. I want a sorted based on the highest value from the [1], [2] and [3]

Comment: @Alex:  `sorted` returns a new list.  `a = sorted(a, reverse=True)`.